# Page jumps when Scrolling with duration setled

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Hi there for almost a day i trying to apply duration for smoth scrolling for page scripted automatic scrolling but however i will do that, page slowly move and then stops and jump ahead to destination. I am working with big bought template named "smartadmin" but i commented out his premade scripting and it still wont work.

I tried:

> ```
>         $('html, body').stop().animate({
>             'scrollTop': "1600"
>         }, 4000)
> ```

Tried sample code from GreenSock, and it gave the same results. I even tried this https://jsfiddle.net/rafarolo/0zt14Lkv/ but it wasn't working on my page. So i was thinking that themplate is doing something wrong, so i commneted out all of its premade JS files. But nothing helped.

The video with the bug
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNbdw6n5czE&feature=emb_title